# python3.9 change a global variable value from inside a function doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, global-variables

Wrote a python script that has a global var named 'md'. I want to change its value from inside a function and then print out this variable. I expect to see the new value after print.

the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.9
import requests
import os
from urllib.parse import urljoin

ip = "2.147.25.51"
md = ''

def get_ip_info (ip):

    global md = '## ipinfo information on IP address ' + ip

print(md)
```

If I don'y use the global inside the function, obviously I will receive an empty string.

My question is why am I getting this error when using 'global md':

```
global md = '## ipinfo information on IP address ' + ip
                                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 4):

Change your function to:

```py
def get_ip_info(ip):
    global md
    md = '## ipinfo information on IP address ' + ip
```

You first need to set `md` to `global` and then *AFTER* set `md` to the IP address.

Comment: Helped indeed! Well done